# Unable to find the mistake in setInterval

Tags: javascript

I have this array:

```
var arr = [];
var i =
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) There:

```
setInterval ( function push(arr) {arr.push(i+1)} , 5*1000)
```

you're shadowing the `arr` variable (that is declaring a new variable which hides the external one). You're thus pushing to `undefined`. There's of course the same problem when you read the values.

2) If you always push `i+1` you always push 1. You probably want `i++`

Simply do

```
setInterval ( function push() {arr.push(i++)} , 5*1000)
```

Comment: can you please explain what is shadowing?

Comment: @MirthfulNahid It means hiding the external variable by declaring a new local one. Because declaring an argument declares a variable in the scope of the function call.

Comment: thanks , i wanted i++

Comment: there is one problem, the whole is printed after 2 sec, if static array . how can i give give 2 sec break for each array element

Comment: @MirthfulNahid I don't understand this requirement. You want to just print an item and not the whole array?

Comment: yes i want to print only one element after 2 sec, from the first to last

Comment: the just log `arr[arr.length-1]` instead of `arr`